# Exchangabilty in CRF generative model for HDP

Tags: bayesian, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

In the HDP Setting, the groups (or documents) are assumed exchangeable between them, and the samples (or words) within each group/topic are also exchangeable.

[Note the Setting chapter here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf)

However, in the described CRF generative model, the ordering matters, using the CRF metaphor, the generative process is as follows:

Let $J$ be the number of restaurants, $N_j$ be the number of customers at each restaurant.
Each customer $ji$ enters restaurant $j$, and is assigned a table according to $\theta_{ij}\sim \sum_{t}\frac{n_{jt}}{\sum_{t'}n_{jt'}+\alpha_0}+\frac{a_0}{\sum_{t'}n_{jt'}+\alpha_0}$

In words- Either a new table, or an existing table, proportional the $\alpha_0$ and the current number of customers in each table.
We do this independently for each one of the groups, attach each customer to a sample $\psi_{jt_{ji}}$ from $G_0$.

We then sample each table dishes in a similar fashion:

$\psi_{jt}\sim \sum_{k}\frac{m_{k}}{\sum_{k'}m_{jk'}+\gamma}+\frac{\gamma}{\sum_{k'}m_{jk'}}$

In words- We choose the dish proportional to each dish popularity and $\gamma$.

The generative process was taken from [here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2698-sharing-clusters-among-related-groups-hierarchical-dirichlet-processes.pdf).

For me, it seems as if the restaurant's sampling order matters, the first restaurant will have a smaller variety of dishes, and when we sample the dishes for the last restaurant, more dishes have been intensified, and there will be a larger variety.

While for the general mixture the ordering really does not matter, each restaurant mixture of dishes will be affected by its order in the sampling.

We can probably resample the dishes a couple of times, similar to what is done when performing inference, or iterate between the groups when sampling, but that seems a bit ad-hoc.

Am I missing something? Generating data with a HDP prior and I want to get it right.

Edit: There is also a version where the dishes are sampled when a new table is instantiated, and not after we are done sampling the tables for all restaurants, but the problem persists in that version as well.

Comment: In the HDP setting, exchangeability does not hold. It holds a weaker version of it, namely partial exchangeability. In the CRF metaphor, partial exchangeability implies that data are exchangeable within each single restaurant but not across different restaurants.

Comment: See my first paragraph, I do not think that the points are exchangeable across different groups, only that the points (customers) are exchangeable within group/restaurant, and that the groups themselves are exchangeable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood the analogy with the documents. However, I still don't get your point, as the same reasoning you present is valid even for a single Chinese Restaurant Process right?

Comment: No, When you look at a single restaurant, you only look at the customers, and between them the exchangeability holds. My point is different, let say you sample 1000 customers in the first restaurant, instantiating 10 dishes, then you move to the next restaurant, you are very likely to see the previous 10 dishes, with some additional new dishes. If you would swap the order of the restaurants, you would probably see the topic count between them swapped as well. With infinite amount of customers at each restaurant exchanageblity still holds, but in practice, the ordering of the restaurants matter

Comment: I think exchangeability holds for each restaurant, and probably for the tables as well, if you look at the union of all tables from all restaurants, but the way the tables are 'spread' among the different restaurants is very much affected from the ordering.

Comment: Ok. How about this, by looking at the HDP model rather than at the CRF, do you see that the groups are exchangeable?

Comment: Yes, the problem I see is with the CRF generative model, not the HDP model by itself. Looking at a 'already generated' model, it's likelihood does not change according to the ordering (customers or restaurants). This came up when I was trying to simluate draws from the CRF, and I noticed that the order in which I take the draws dictate how the topics are spread among the restaurants.

Comment: Ok I see your point. However exchangeability does not mean that the tentative model does not depend on the order. Rather, it satay that if you have a sequence data in groups and permute the labeling of the groups, the marginal likelihood does not change. This can be shown for example when you have two groups with with a couple of datapoints each, and write down by hand the CRF process. By permuting the groups you are only permuting the numerators, the denominators are unchanged and overall the marginal is equal